# How to get Data from firebase I tried it many time but not accessing?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am accessing data from firebase but its not working why?

```
   ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

ref contain error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because ref is not defined.

DatabaseReference ref;
ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();